# iOS: Set Property before Changing View

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im setting up a IBAction to change views after a table row is selected & the done button is pressed.

However when I run presentViewController:animated I loose my navigationController.

So then I've got no way to go anywhere, and then if I do instead a 'performSegueWithIdentifier' my properties don't save.. So no values are passed... For example:

```
 ViewController *addViewController = (ViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"V_SignIn"];
 addViewController.LoadAction = @"NoSession";
 [addViewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
 [self presentViewController:addViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

^^ That code works but removes my Navigation Toolbar...

```
ViewController *addViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
addViewController.LoadAction = @"TEST";
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];
```

^^ That performs segue fine, but the 'LoadAction' var equals (NULL) when I NSLog it in the new view.

Basically, how can I set the @property without needing to follow through changing views with the addViewController var? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first scenario, instead of `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`, you need to use `-pushViewController:animated:` on your navigation controller to avoid hiding it (and conversely, you'll use `-popViewController:animated:`, also called on the navigation controller, to dismiss it, rather than `-dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`):

```
ViewController *addViewController = (ViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"V_SignIn"];
addViewController.LoadAction = @"NoSession";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addViewController animated:YES];
```

As Wain notes, in your second scenario, you will need to do your configuration of `addViewController` in `-prepareForSegue:sender:` like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue"]) {
        ViewController *addViewController = (ViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        // perform setup on addViewController
        addViewController.LoadAction = @"TEST";
        // ...
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someOtherSegue"]) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the second section of code, just use `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue" sender:self];` to create and display the new view. Also implement `- prepareForSegue:sender:` (in the view controller that triggers the above code) to perform the configuration of the new view controller.